# Use Lua filter to set pandoc template variable

Tags: lua, pandoc, quarto

My goal is to input different text in the template based on a single variable in the yaml.
Below is a minimal attempt, but I can't get it to work.
I'm looking for a Lua filter that set the variable `$selected$` based on the value of `$switch$`.
In practice, I'll set several template variables based on that variable.
The idea is to have one more generic template instead of many templates with relative few differences.

`pandoc index.md --to html --from markdown --output index.html --template template.html --lua-filter=filter.lua`

file `index.md`

```
---
title: "test"
switch: "a"
---
Some text
```

file `template.html`

```
<html>
  <title>$title$</title>
  <body>
    <h1>$selected$</h1>
    <h2>$switch$</h2>
    $body$
  </body>
</html>
```

file `filter.lua`

```
local function choose(info)
  local result
  if (info == "a")
  then
    result = "first choise"
  else
    result = "alternative"
  end
  return result
end

return {
  {
    Meta = function(meta)
      meta.title, meta.selected = choose(meta.switch)
      return meta
    end
  }
}
```

desired output

```
<html>
  <title>test</title>
<body>
  <h1>first choise</h1>
  <h2>a</h2>
  <p>Some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the result I get

```
<html>
  <title>alternative</title>
<body>
  <h1></h1>
  <h2>a</h2>
  <p>Some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that metadata values *look* like strings, but can be of some other type. Here, they are *Inlines*, as can be checked with this filter:

```lua
function Meta (meta)
  print(pandoc.utils.type(meta.switch))
end
```

The easiest solution is to convert the value to a string with `pandoc.utils.stringify`:

```lua
    Meta = function(meta)
      meta.selected = choose(pandoc.utils.stringify(meta.switch))
      return meta
    end
```

The filter should work as expected now.